# Issue with rock, paper, scissors and max. score on if

Tags: javascript

I finished a rock, paper scissors exercise and added some DOM and events to it with the help of the community, so good so far but I am having a single issue that I can't figure it out how to fix:

The problem is if you keep playing without pressing the "Play again!" button to restart the game it will keep counting so if you score 5 and computer 3 then it will keep adding more numbers to the score so it will add more restart buttons to the page.

So, I want the game to end when userScore or computerScore scores 5 points, so when this happens it will show a winner and the button. I don't want to keep adding numbers to scores if the user keeps clicking.

I have tried a few things that didn't work: I tried a for loop, I tried two separate ifs, I tried with Math.max method and nothing worked. Can someone please give me some guidance? MY logic here is failing.

Thanks a lot.

```js
// Global DOM variables
const $selectBtn = document.querySelectorAll("[data-selector]");
const $displayUserScore = document.querySelector("#user-score");
const $displayComputerScore = document.querySelector("#computer-score")
const $showScore = document.querySelector("h5");
const $theWinnerIs = document.querySelector('#result-winner');
const $refreshBtnContainer = document.querySelector('#refresh-button-container');
const $icons = ["", "", "✂️"];

// Score vaiables
const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

// For each button of buttons...
$selectBtn.forEach(function(button){
    
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let computerOption = computerRandom() // Store random computer play on var
        const userOption = button.dataset.selector; // userOption is equal to data-selector attribute
        

        // Invoke functions plays the game and shows final winner.
        playGame(userOption, computerOption);
        theWinner();
        
        // Add function with results
        function playGame(userOption, computerOption) {

            if (userOption === "rock") {
                if (computerOption === "scissors") {
                    userScore++;
                    $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[2] + "</span>" + ", you BEAT him!";
                } else if (computerOption === "paper") {
                    computerScore++;
                    $displayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[1] + "</span>" + ", you LOSE!";
                } else if (userOption === computerOption) {
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "Draw!";
                }
            }

            if (userOption === "paper") {
                if (computerOption === "rock") {
                    userScore++;
                    $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[0] + "</span>" + ", you BEAT him!";
                } else if (computerOption === "scissors") {
                    computerScore++;
                    $displayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[2] + "</span>" + ", you LOSE!";
                } else if (userOption === computerOption) {
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "Draw!";
                }
            }

            if (userOption === "scissors") {
                if (computerOption === "paper") {
                    userScore++;
                    $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[1] + "</span>" + ", you BEAT him!";
                } else if (computerOption === "rock") {
                    computerScore++;
                    $displayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[0] + "</span>" + ", you LOSE!";
                } else if (userOption === computerOption) {
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "Draw!";
                }
            }

        }
        
        // Add a winners text function
        function theWinner() {
            if (userScore === 5) {
                $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = "You!";
            } else if (computerScore === 5) {
                $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = "The machine!";
            }
        }

        if (userScore === 5 || computerScore === 5) {
            const $refreshBtn = document.createElement('button');
            $refreshBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Play again!"));
            $refreshBtn.className = "refresh-btn";
            $refreshBtnContainer.appendChild($refreshBtn);
            
                $refreshBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                userScore = 0;
                computerScore = 0;
                $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
                $displayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
                $showScore.innerHTML = "";
                $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = "";
                $refreshBtnContainer.innerHTML= "";
            })   
        }

    })
    
})

// Random computer choice
function computerRandom () {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
    return choices[randomNumber];
}
```

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.btn-selector {
    font-size: 4em;
    background: rebeccapurple;
    margin: .1em;
    padding: .2em;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 20%;
    transition: 150ms;
}
.btn-selector:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

#results {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.score {
    margin-right: 1em;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: italic;
}

h3 {
    color: rebeccapurple;
    font-style: italic;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

h5 {
    margin-top: 7px;
    color: olive;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.icon {
    font-size: 3em;
}

.refresh-btn {
    padding: .8em;
    background: rebeccapurple;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-style: bold;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rock, paper and scissors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <button class="btn-selector" data-selector="rock"></button>
        <button class="btn-selector" data-selector="paper"></button>
        <button class="btn-selector" data-selector="scissors">✂️</button>
        <div id="results">
        <h4>You: <span id="user-score" class="score" data-user-score>0</span></h4>
        <h4>Computer: <span id="computer-score" class="score" data-computer-score>0</span></h4>
    </div>
    <h5></h5>
        <div>
            <h3>And the winner is...</h3>
            <h3 id="result-winner"></h3>
        </div>
        <div id="refresh-button-container">
            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically What your condition is

`Hey whenever any one of three button is click run Winner Function`

and Inside winner function you checking if score is 5 then insert a button
but You are not disabling buttons

**So Should You Do**

You can either disabled buttons or instead of appending play again button you can toggle its visibility

Comment: Yeah I know what it does and that is what I was trying to fix but it didn't work. I will look into toggle stuff with JS, thanks.

About the adding values to the code, any way to fix that so if you keep clicking it won't add more values until you restart?

Thanks!

Comment: You can archieve this by making a boolean `isGameOver` and check if `isGameOver` if it is then Dont run Winner Function

Answer (score 1):

Here is full code, with changes, so you can try:

```js
// Global DOM variables
const $selectBtn = document.querySelectorAll("[data-selector]");
const $displayUserScore = document.querySelector("#user-score");
const $displayComputerScore = document.querySelector("#computer-score")
const $showScore = document.querySelector("h5");
const $theWinnerIs = document.querySelector('#result-winner');
const $refreshBtnContainer = document.querySelector('#refresh-button-container');
const $icons = ["", "", "✂️"];

// Score vaiables
const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

// For each button of buttons...
$selectBtn.forEach(function(button){
    
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let computerOption = computerRandom() // Store random computer play on var
        const userOption = button.dataset.selector; // userOption is equal to data-selector attribute
        

        // Invoke functions plays the game and shows final winner.
        playGame(userOption, computerOption);
        theWinner();
        
        // Add function with results
        function playGame(userOption, computerOption) {

            if (userOption === "rock") {
                if (computerOption === "scissors") {
                    userScore++;
                    $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[2] + "</span>" + ", you BEAT him!";
                } else if (computerOption === "paper") {
                    computerScore++;
                    $displayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[1] + "</span>" + ", you LOSE!";
                } else if (userOption === computerOption) {
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "Draw!";
                }
            }

            if (userOption === "paper") {
                if (computerOption === "rock") {
                    userScore++;
                    $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[0] + "</span>" + ", you BEAT him!";
                } else if (computerOption === "scissors") {
                    computerScore++;
                    $displayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[2] + "</span>" + ", you LOSE!";
                } else if (userOption === computerOption) {
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "Draw!";
                }
            }

            if (userOption === "scissors") {
                if (computerOption === "paper") {
                    userScore++;
                    $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[1] + "</span>" + ", you BEAT him!";
                } else if (computerOption === "rock") {
                    computerScore++;
                    $displayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+"<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[0] + "</span>" + ", you LOSE!";
                } else if (userOption === computerOption) {
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "Draw!";
                }
            }

        }
        
        // Add a winners text function
        function theWinner() {
            if (userScore === 5) {
                $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = "You!";
            } else if (computerScore === 5) {
                $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = "The machine!";
            }
        }

        if (userScore === 5 || computerScore === 5) {
            const $refreshBtn = document.createElement('button');
            $refreshBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Play again!"));
            $refreshBtn.className = "refresh-btn";
            $refreshBtnContainer.appendChild($refreshBtn);
            
           for (var i = 0, len = $selectBtn.length; i<len; i++){
           $selectBtn[i].disabled = true; }  //disable
          

                $refreshBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                userScore = 0;
                computerScore = 0;
                $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
                $displayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
                $showScore.innerHTML = "";
                $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = "";
                $refreshBtnContainer.innerHTML= "";
                for (var i = 0, len = $selectBtn.length; i<len; i++){
                $selectBtn[i].disabled = false; }  //enable
                })   
        }

    })
    
})

// Random computer choice
function computerRandom () {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
    return choices[randomNumber];
}
```

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.btn-selector {
    font-size: 4em;
    background: rebeccapurple;
    margin: .1em;
    padding: .2em;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 20%;
    transition: 150ms;
}
.btn-selector:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

#results {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.score {
    margin-right: 1em;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: italic;
}

h3 {
    color: rebeccapurple;
    font-style: italic;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

h5 {
    margin-top: 7px;
    color: olive;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.icon {
    font-size: 3em;
}

.refresh-btn {
    padding: .8em;
    background: rebeccapurple;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-style: bold;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rock, paper and scissors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <button class="btn-selector" data-selector="rock"></button>
        <button class="btn-selector" data-selector="paper"></button>
        <button class="btn-selector" data-selector="scissors">✂️</button>
        <div id="results">
        <h4>You: <span id="user-score" class="score" data-user-score>0</span></h4>
        <h4>Computer: <span id="computer-score" class="score" data-computer-score>0</span></h4>
    </div>
    <h5></h5>
        <div>
            <h3>And the winner is...</h3>
            <h3 id="result-winner"></h3>
        </div>
        <div id="refresh-button-container">
            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would just disable those buttons when the score is === 5 (one of the possible ways is using for loop), and then just enable them same way back when you click the refresh button.

```
if (userScore === 5 || computerScore === 5) {
        const $refreshBtn = document.createElement('button');
        $refreshBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Play again!"));
        $refreshBtn.className = "refresh-btn";
        $refreshBtnContainer.appendChild($refreshBtn);
        
       for (var i = 0, len = $selectBtn.length; i<len; i++){
       $selectBtn[i].disabled = true; }  //disable
      

            $refreshBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            userScore = 0;
            computerScore = 0;
            $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
            $displayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
            $showScore.innerHTML = "";
            $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = "";
            $refreshBtnContainer.innerHTML= "";
            for (var i = 0, len = $selectBtn.length; i<len; i++){
            $selectBtn[i].disabled = false; }  //enable
            })
```

And, by the way, the rock emoji is not working in my case! (Using Google Chrome)

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, I will fix the emoji. For some reason your code doesn't work on me, I think the for loop has 4 values instead of 3? Tho I get the idea but it doesn't work... and one more question, with $selectBtn has the [i]? Just asking to learn more. Thanks

Comment: Okay, my bad, I just set the "len" var outside the for and worked like a charm, tho I don't get why if every item of the $selectBtn is disabled (disabled: true) it's still clickable...

Comment: @Quickpois0n About your question, yeah, the $selectBtn has the [i], what would represent the index of an array in this situation. That is because you selected those items via .querySelectorAll("*[*data-selector*]*");  which means that you basically created an array of elements.
My advice is, just copy my code snippet inside of your code, because I've done the same, and it is working as it's supposed to.

Comment: Yeah I read it several times to understand it, I am more interesting on learning and work my logic rather than have the work done, but in your case you did both so I am grateful, again, thank you very much!

Comment: That is a great approach. I'm glad you are doing it that way, but, there is an explanation if you ever get stuck. Wish you all the best!