# How can I store a value on button click?

Tags: javascript

I'm a JS newbie and currently following "The Odin Project". I made a simple rock-paper-scissors game in a console, but now I want to implement it with card pictures and a score in simple HTML page.

How do I store a value based upon user click(etc. I click on a paper and it saves it value `userGuess = "paper"`.

```
        <div class="boxes">
            <div class="box">
                <button class="rock">
                    <img class="rock-img" src="images/rock.png" alt="Rock image">
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <button class="paper">
                    <img class="paper-img" src="images/paper.png" alt="">
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <button onclick="logValue()" class="scissors" id="3">
                    <img class="scissors-img" src="images/scissors.png" alt="">
                </button>
            </div>
```

```
let myArray = [
    'Rock',
    'Paper',
    'Scissors'
];

let userGuess;

function playRound() {

    /* Only part of this game that I had to google for.
    Didn't know how to randomly choose from array. */
    let computerGuess = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
    userGuess = prompt("Choose from 'Rock', 'Paper' or 'Scissors'.");

    if (computerGuess == 'Rock') {

        if (userGuess.toLowerCase() == 'rock') {
            console.log(`It's a tie! You choose ${userGuess} while PC choose ${computerGuess}.`)
        }

        else if (userGuess.toLowerCase() == 'scissors') {
            console.log(`You lost! You choose ${userGuess} while PC choose ${computerGuess}.`)
        }

        else {
            console.log(`You won! You choose ${userGuess} while PC choose ${computerGuess}.`)
        }
    }

    else if (computerGuess == 'Paper') {

        if (userGuess.toLowerCase() == 'paper') {
            console.log(`It's a tie! You choose ${userGuess} while PC choose ${computerGuess}.`)
        }

        else if (userGuess.toLowerCase() == 'scissors') {
            console.log(`You won! You choose ${userGuess} while PC choose ${computerGuess}.`)
        }

        else {
            console.log(`You lost! You choose ${userGuess} while PC choose ${computerGuess}.`)
        }
    }

    else {
        if (userGuess.toLowerCase() == 'paper') {

            console.log(`You lost! You choose ${userGuess} while PC choose ${computerGuess}.`)
        }

        else if (userGuess.toLowerCase() == 'scissors') {
            console.log(`It's a tie! You choose ${userGuess} while PC choose ${computerGuess}.`)
        }

        else {
            console.log(`You won! You choose ${userGuess} while PC choose ${computerGuess}.`)
        }
    }


}

function game() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        playRound()
    }
}
```

I'm messing with it for some time now and just unable to solve it :/

Comment: Why do you have `onclick` defined for your scissors button to call a function that hasn't been defined?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was trying something out and forgot to remove it(didn't work).

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: U made a ```logValue``` function that I tested if a value from that button(eg. rock) would print out in a console.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72560531/issue-with-rock-paper-scissors-and-max-score-on-if/72560834#72560834 I think that you can find a solution based on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Define the buttons in variables and add eventListeners to it.

`let paperBtn = document.querySelector('.paper');`

And then add a EventListener

```
paperBtn.addEventListener('click', () => { // ASSIGN A VALUE TO USERGUESS  });
```

Is this what you're looking for?